# Why can't I use get_children_by_id() on this widget

Tags: awesome-wm

I want to access the internal widgets but it gives me an error, that I can't index a nil value.

My widget:

```lua
local previewWidget = wibox()

previewWidget:setup {
    widget = wibox.widget {
        {
            widget = wibox.widget {
                {
                    widget = awful.widget.clienticon,
                    client = "", 
                    id = "clientIcon"
                },
                {
                    widget = wibox.widget.textbox,
                    id = "titleText"
                },
                nil
            },
            layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal,
            id = "titleBox"
        },
        {
            widget = wibox.widget.imagebox,
            id = "clientImage"
        },
        nil
    },  
    id = "previewBox",
    layout = wibox.layout.align.vertical,
    border_width = 10, 
    border_color = "FF0000",
}
```

This command doesn't give error:

```lua
local previewBox = previewWidget:get_children_by_id("previewBox")[1]
```

But this does:

```lua
local titleBox = previewWidget:get_children_by_id("titleBox")[1]
local clientIcon = previewWidget:get_children_by_id("clientIcon")[1]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you leave out the inner call to `wibox.widget`? Specifically, replace `widget = wibox.widget {` with just `{`.

Comment: Actually, I think you should get rid of all calls to `wibox.widget`. `:setup` already does that for you and running that "magic" several times creates several "universes" where IDs can be resolved and the inner ones do not know about the outer ones and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local previewWidget = wibox.widget {
    {
        {
            widget = awful.widget.clienticon,
            client = "",
            id = "clientIcon"
        },
        {
            widget = wibox.widget.textbox,
            id = "titleText"
        },
        nil,

        layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal,
        id = "titleBox"
    },
    {
        widget = wibox.widget.imagebox,
        id = "clientImage"
    },
    nil,

    layout = wibox.layout.align.vertical,
    id = "previewBox",
}
```

I incorrectly used the layout:
All 3 widgets needs to be where the layout is called

```lua
local some_widget = wibox.widget {
   { widget nr.1 },
   { widget nr.2 },
   { widget nr.3 },
   layout = wibox.layout.align.vertical
}
```

P.S. it's enough to declare a layout without a widget